# phpUnit - assertQuery fails with

Tags: php, zend-framework, testing, phpunit, assert

I am having trouble with an assertQuery().  In the html I have (verified by outputting the body)

```
<input type="text" name="LASTNAME" id="LASTNAME" value="" maxlength="25" size="20" />
```

So I wrote a query for it to test to make sure this element exists and that the value is empty

```
    $this->assertQuery('input#LASTNAME[value=""]', 1);
```

PhpUnit says the assertion fails

> Failed asserting node DENOTED BY
>   input#LASTNAME[value=""] EXISTS

Can you give me some insight into why this assertion fails and how to write it properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Zend Framework's code that converts the CSS selector to an XPath query is broken. It doesn't add the required `@` before the attribute name. Use this, albeit incorrect CSS, assertion:

```
$this->assertQuery('input#LASTNAME[@value=""]', 1);
```

See [this forum thread](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Zend-Test-PHPUnit-ControllerTestCase-asserting-a-checkbox-is-checked-td2068157.html) for details.

Update: The [issue was reported](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9764) and [fixed in release 1.10](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9764?focusedCommentId=40279&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_40279), so you could upgrade your Zend Framework as an alternative to using an invalid CSS selector.

Comment: Very nice and complete answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `XPath` instead of `CSS` selectors, and thus skip the `CSS` to `XPath` conversion performed by `Zend_Dom_Query`:

```
$this->assertXpath( '//input[@id="LASTNAME"][@value=""]' );
```